# toggleClass() in ONE child DIV inside specyfic LI element in ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

I have situation like below:

```
<div class="row folio">
  <ul class="fo-content">
    <li id="xxx">
      <p>Paragraph</p>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="inner">
        <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="xxx3"><p>Paragraph</p>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="inner">
        <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I try to make addClass() on div with class "inner" after click specific `<li>` element. I allready have animations and several other actions here like below:

```
wideFolio: function() {

            var list = $( '.fo-content li' );
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var inner = $( ".fo-content li .inner" );

            $( '.fo-content li' ).on( 'click', function(a){
                a.preventDefault();

                if( $( this ).css( "height" ) == "270px" ) {
                    inner.removeClass("opened");
                    list.animate({ height: "270px" }, 500 );
                    $(this).animate({height: "450px" }, 
                    { 
                    duration: 500, 
                    complete: function() {
                        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top },
                            {
                                duration:  500,
                                complete: function() {

                                    $(this).find(".inner").addClass("opened");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $(this).animate({ height: "270px" }, 500 );
                    inner.removeClass("opened");
                }           
            });
        }
```

Please, focus only on last `complete:` where I try to addClass(), because everytime I try make method like find(), closest(), children(), doesn't work for me. Find() method is adding class, but to all divs inside all `<li>` elements,but I need it's happen only in one, clicked  element from list.. Maybe I'am too tired today for it... Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looking for an element inside the entire body, you should only look it inside the element which invoked the event.

```
        $( '.fo-content li' ).on( 'click', function(a){
            $this_li = this; // ADD THIS LINE
            a.preventDefault();

            if( $( this ).css( "height" ) == "270px" ) {
                inner.removeClass("opened");
                list.animate({ height: "270px" }, 500 );
                $(this).animate({height: "450px" }, 
                { 
                duration: 500, 
                complete: function() {
                    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top },
                        {
                            duration:  500,
                            complete: function() {
                                $($this_li).find(".inner").addClass("opened"); // CHANGE THIS LINE
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                $(this).animate({ height: "270px" }, 500 );
                inner.removeClass("opened");
            }           
        });
```

Comment: You're Boss @DinoMyte :) I guess now I am understand.